# Identifying Included Work items in TFS 2015 Release Management

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to understand the process for vNext Builds and Release Management as far as identifying what work items are included.

If I have a build set up on every check-in (each time a work is completed), then each of those Builds will have one work item linked.  I can then trigger a Release deployment of those Builds to a QA environment, but then each Release only identifies that one item as being linked - not any others that have been included since our last production release. Since there could be multiple Release Deploys to QA prior to a Deploy to Production, it's confusing trying to filter through all the Releases.

I'm trying to find a good way to see all work items included in Builds/Releases since the last production deployment.  Am I misunderstanding how to use this? Should I be using the same Release and just changing the targeted Build each time?  It seems like it bases "included work items" off the checked in work-items in between the last build and the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Release Management, It compares current release with the last release to show the work items included in current release. You only see one work item is because that you have configured TFS to build every check-in and trigger the release for every build. If you trigger a release after two builds, you will see two work items included in the two builds. The latest version of Visual Studio Team Service has support selecting a release version to compare with current version to list the included changes and work items, but this hasn't been implemented into On-premise TFS yet.

So for now, you can create another release definition and link it to the same build to deploy the build to production manually. Then you can track the included work items from this release definition. Or you can create an app/powershell script to read the build version in the production release and then get the included the work items via [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/overview).